# add new layer to Arc Server's Services

Tags: layer, arcgis, arcgis-server

I have a MapServer Service published in ArcGis For Server. I want  to add a new Layer to this Service. how can I do it?
any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to republish the service using ArcGIS for Desktop if you want to add new layers to an existing service. For details, see the documentation: [Overwriting a service in ArcGIS for Desktop](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Overwriting_a_service_in_ArcGIS_for_Desktop/015400000297000000/)

Another option is to publish a second service with the new layer and then use both services in your application.